# ASP.Net session timing out problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a single-page website that makes heavy use of `AJAX`. User actions are all sent to a URL in the form of e.g. `requests.aspx?obid=1&verb=shownotes`

Session expiration on my hosting provider is set at 5 minutes, which is too short. I am struggling to get them to change that.

I have tried using `setInterval` to send a request to the server every 30 seconds, but the sessions still expires after 5 minutes. The information in the `setInterval` request looks just like a user request, but I guess the server isn't fooled.

I have disabled caching with `jQuery`.

I do not use cookies.

Could it be that the `setInterval` request is being cached on the server itself? Should I append a random string to this request?

What is the best way to ensure that the session stays alive?

EDIT: The following is Request headers copied from Chrome Developer Tools:

Request headers for typical user action:

```
POST /requests.aspx?obid=0&otid=203&verb=display&param1=0&param2=0&param3=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: applify.co.za
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://applify.co.za
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://applify.co.za/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4li3ilr0bsb5yc1uf5oy1pd1
```

Request headers for `setInterval` action:

```
POST /requests.aspx?obid=0&otid=545&verb=donothing&param1=&param2=&param3= HTTP/1.1
Host: applify.co.za
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://applify.co.za
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://applify.co.za/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4li3ilr0bsb5yc1uf5oy1pd1
```

Both look pretty much the same.

Comment: Are you using forms authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding  a timestamp suffix eg :

(via JS)

```
var t='requests.aspx?obid=1&verb=shownotes';
t+='&'+(1*new Date())
```

continue with request....

or via c#

`...requests.aspx?obid=1&verb=shownotes&t=<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks%>`

p.s. post your set interval code so we can see it.

NB

- jquery ajax has `cache` property which is `true` by default (IMHO)

  try set it to `false`. it would add a timestamp.
- Can you post the code for the aspx code ? ( I want to see if you do ClearHeaders there or Response.End....

Comment: I've already tried `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`. Will try the timestamp suffix.

Comment: @CorneBeukes look at chrome developertool bar  , for  the headers and post it in your question

Comment: @CorneBeukes what about the **response** headers ? also , I dont see any suffix for the request

Comment: At the moment the response headers are identical, expect content length. I will retest later today with the suffix and give feedback.

Comment: I'm looking for the response code (200 or 304). cuz polling a handler - should extend the timeout. ( also - post your aspx code  , you might do something there which casing Thread.Abort)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the session timeout in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60"  />
</system.web>
```

Because you are not using cookies, you may want to specifically specify `cookieless=true`.

Comment: The timeout is controlled by the hosting provider, and setting the sessionstate in `web.config` has no effect.